# How to add android resource folder in flutter project?

Tags: dart, flutter

When I create XML resource directory then display the error 'Cannot find resource directory for module Module'  how to resolve this error in flutter project??

Comment: Sounds like https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#sharing-assets-with-the-underlying-platform but I don't know if this is the same for modules

Answer (score 1):

I face this problem too and the only work around that i found was open the project as a native project in other android studio instance and then create the resource directories. You can do this selecting 'app' module on android studio open project dialog.

[image: android studio open dialog]